# $_POST not getting initialized

Tags: php

I am using php for the first time. I understand that creating a HTML form initilizes variable like `$_POST, $_GET, $_REQUEST` etc.

I have the following code in my AddItem.php:

```
<?php require_once('../get-common/keys.php') ?>
<?php require_once('../get-common/eBaySession.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>AddItem</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM action="AddItem.php" method="post">
<TABLE cellpadding="2" border="0">
    <TR>
        <TD>listingType</TD>
        <TD>
          <select name="listingType">
            <option value="Chinese">Chinese</option>
            <option value="Dutch">Dutch</option>
            <option value="FixedPriceItem">Fixed Price Item</option>
            <option value="StoresFixedPrice">Stores Fixed Price</option>
          </select>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>primaryCategory</TD>
        <TD>
          <select name="primaryCategory">
        <option value="14111">Test Category</option>
            <option value="57889">Boys Athletic Pants</option>
            <option value="57890">Boys Corduroys Pants</option>
            <option value="57891">Boys Jeans Pants</option>
            <option value="57892">Boys Khakis Pants</option>
          </select>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>itemTitle</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="itemTitle" value="TEST IN SANDBOX BEFORE PROD - DO NOT BID" size=30></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>itemDescription</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="itemDescription" value="TEST IN SANDBOX BEFORE PROD - DO NOT BID - This will incur prod listing fees" size=30></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD>listingDuration</TD>
        <TD>
          <select name="listingDuration">
            <option value="Days_1">1 day</option>
            <option value="Days_3">3 days</option>
            <option value="Days_5">5 days</option>
            <option value="Days_7">7 days</option>
          </select>
          (defaults to GTC = 30 days for Store)
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>startPrice</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="startPrice" value="<?php echo rand(1,200) / 100 ?>"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>buyItNowPrice</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="buyItNowPrice" value="<?php echo rand(299,599) / 100; ?>"> (set to 0.0 for Store)</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>quantity</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type="text" name="quantity" value="1"> (must be 1 for Chinese)</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" align="right"><INPUT type="submit" name="submit" value="AddItem"></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</FORM>


<?php
    if(isset($_POST['listingType']))
    //....some more code
?>
```

On running the file using `php -f AddItem.php` only the HTML gets printed. Nothing inside the `<?php ?>` gets executed. This is because $_POST is not initialized (prints `Array` on echo).

Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here. Why is the $_POST not getting initialized?

Thanks

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan : It gives `Array()`

Comment: The $_POST array will only contain data submitted by an HTTP POST request. Since you have made no such request, it will be empty.

Comment: @user876345 : `array(0) {}`

Answer (score 9):

There is no HTTP call in php command line execution in your case, its pretty normal that $_POST will be   empty.

As a work around, i would suggest doing something like the following:

1. Write a script that would run under a web server like Apache.
2. Include or Require your PHP script.

The following code snippet will clarify my claims:

```
<?php
  require_once('/path/to/your_command_line_php_script.php');

  // Now inside your_command_line_php_script.php you will have $_POST available and initialized.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: is there a way I can make HTTP call on command line execution?

Comment: Yes, you may use cURL

Answer (score 1):

If you run php in the way you do. You are executing the script. But not actually posting the form. You will have to submit the form through a browser to populate the `$_POST` vars

Comment: Its a standalone php file. I dont have domain or anything else. Please could you tell me how can I submit through the browser? Would `file:///home/user/location` suffice?